# how to give database name in SQLAlchemy URI?

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql, apache-superset

I am using Apache Superset and to connect to the SQLServer, I am using the below url which works fine but connects to master DB on MSSQL. I wanted to connect to another DB on MSSQL but do not know how to do that

`mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<freetds_name>/?charset=utf8`

Is there a way I can explicitly mention the DB name in the url ?
Another issue I have is my db name has space in it, it is "Data Analytics"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mssql+pymssql://user:pass@host/db
```

Reference: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the required parameter where I can just mention the name of the DB in url. Although there are ways of doing it but if you are using freetds_name, I have not see any option of setting DB name.
I tried setting default Database name in odbc.ini but for some reason it did not work.

The easiest way is to execute any of the below SQL

`EXEC '<Login_name in Quotes>', '<DB name in Quotes>'`

OR

`ALTER LOGIN <Login_Name_noQuotes>
with DEFAULT_DATABASE = <DB_name_no_quotes`

Since my DB name had space in it, I implemented the first statement  and it worked.

You can check the Default DB by executing below SQL

`select name,
       loginname,
       dbname as DefaultDB
from syslogins`